# Have IDE suggest mutations and actions when commiting or dispatching

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuex, intellisense

Currently I am using Vuex in a Vue 3 Typescript project. I have something like this:

```
import { createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store } from 'vuex';
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue';


export interface State {
    foo: string;
  }
  
  export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol();
  
  export const store = createStore<State>({
      state: {foo: 'foo'},
      mutations: { 
        changeFoo(state: State, payload: string){
            state.foo = payload
        }
      },
      actions: { 
        setFooToBar({commit}){
         commit('changeFoo', 'bar')
      }}
  })

  export function useStoreTyped() {
    return baseUseStore(key);
  }
```

Then later in a component I type out:

```
import { useStoreTyped } from "../store";

const store = useStoreTyped();

function() {
   store.distpatch('... // at this point I would like to see a list of my actions
}
```

This setup is nice because in my IDE it if I start typing `store.state.` VS Code will popup a little box that suggests the props on my state object (in this example .foo). However I am not getting the same behavior when I try and commit mutations or dispatch actions. How can I give the vuex store object the mutation and action names so it can provide suggestions (intellisense) for these?

Comment: I'm not a vue expert but it seems that `dispatch` as well as `createStore` does not infer action names. What exactly do you want to infer?

Comment: So in the course of writing functions that impact the vuex store I call `store.dispatch` and sometimes `store.commit` the first argument of each is the name of the mutation or action that ought to be dispatched or committed. I would like to see a list the available mutations and actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add types? Yes you can. Whether or not you should add types (instead of waiting for `vuex` to add better types) is a different question.

### Basic Solution

Here is a way to add type hints to the `commit` and `dispatch` methods of the `store` instance:

```js
import { createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store, ActionHandler, DispatchOptions, CommitOptions } from 'vuex';
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue';


export interface State {
    foo: string;
}

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol();

const storeInitializer = {
    state: { foo: 'foo' } as State,
    mutations: {
        changeFoo(state: State, payload: string) {
            state.foo = payload
        },
        rearrangeFoo(state: State) {
            state.foo = state.foo.split('').sort().join()
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setFooToBar: (({ commit }) => {
            commit('changeFoo', 'bar')
        }) as ActionHandler<State, State>
    }
}

export type TypedDispatchAndAction<T extends { mutations: any, actions: any }> = {
  dispatch: (type: keyof T['actions'], payload?: any, options?: DispatchOptions) => Promise<any>
  commit: (type: keyof T['mutations'], payload?: any, options?:  CommitOptions) => void
}

export const store = createStore<State>(storeInitializer)

export function useStoreTyped() {
    const keyedStore = baseUseStore(key);

    return keyedStore as typeof keyedStore & TypedDispatchAndAction<typeof storeInitializer>
}
```

This method has some downsides: It's not very graceful, and it doesn't do full type checking if a `mutation` or `action` requires a `payload`

### Complex Solution

This solution adds type hints for the `key` parameter of both `commit` and `dispatch` as well as adding type checking for the `payload` parameter

```js
import { createStore, useStore as baseUseStore, Store, DispatchOptions, CommitOptions, ActionContext } from 'vuex';
import { InjectionKey } from 'vue';

type Length<L extends any[]> = L['length']

type Function<P extends any[] = any, R extends any = any> = (...args: P) => R

type ParamLength<Fn extends Function> = Length<Parameters<Fn>>

type P1<Fn extends (...args: any) => any> = Parameters<Fn>[1]

type Payload<H extends Function> = ParamLength<H> extends 2
    ? P1<H> extends infer X ? X : never
    : never

type TypedDispatchOrCommit<A extends { [key: string]: Function }, Options, Return, K extends keyof A = keyof A> = {
    <I extends K>(key: I, ...args: {
        0: [],
        1: [payload: Payload<A[I]>]
    }[Payload<A[I]> extends never ? 0 : 1]): Return
    <I extends K>(key: I, ...args: {
        0: [payload: undefined, options: Options],
        1: [payload: Payload<A[I]>, options: Options]
    }[Payload<A[I]> extends never ? 0 : 1]): Return
}

export type TypedDispatchAndAction<T extends { mutations: any, actions: any }> = {
  dispatch: TypedDispatchOrCommit<T['actions'], DispatchOptions, Promise<any>>
  commit: TypedDispatchOrCommit<T['mutations'], CommitOptions, void>
}



export interface State {
    foo: string;
}

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<State>> = Symbol();

const storeInitializer = {
    state: { foo: 'foo' } as State,
    mutations: {
        changeFoo(state: State, payload: string) {
            state.foo = payload
        },
        rearrangeFoo(state: State) {
            state.foo = state.foo.split('').sort().join()
        }
    },
    actions: {
        setFooToBar({ commit }: ActionContext<State, State>) {
            commit('changeFoo', 'bar')
        },
        setFoo({ commit }: ActionContext<State, State>, payload: string) {
            commit('changeFoo', payload)
        }
    }
}

export const store = createStore<State>(storeInitializer)

export function useStoreTyped() {
    const keyedStore = baseUseStore(key);

    return keyedStore as Omit<typeof keyedStore, 'dispatch' | 'commit'> & TypedDispatchAndAction<typeof storeInitializer>
}
```

Despite its downside of not being very intelligible, the above code does pass the following tests:

```js
import { useTypedStore } from '../store'

const store = useTypedStore()

// expected: Pass, actual: Pass, returns void
store.commit('rearrangeFoo')
// expected: Fail, actual: Fail, returns void
store.commit('changeFoo')
// expected: Pass, actual: Pass, returns void
//    also gives typehint of string for payload
store.commit('changeFoo', 'bar')
```

The same is true for dispatch, except it returns a `Promise<any>`

### Conclusion

You can get types, but the best solution is for `vuex` to overhaul their types for better type hinting (assuming that fits their project vision).

##### Notes

This was all done on `vs-code` with the following packages:

```
typescript@^4.5.5
vuex@^4.0.2
vue@^3.2.31
```